# clamdscan returns "Clamav Daemon cannot be started" but clamd is running

Tags: php, clamav, symfony

I am using clamdscan to scan files uploaded to a website. If I run clamdscan from the command line it works fine. However, if I call from a PHP script it throws an exception:

```
App\Util\Exception\Company\AntivirusNotRunningException
Clamav Daemon cannot be started
```

I assume that Clamav Daemon is clamd but that is running:

[image]

I have tried changing the owner of clamd from root to apache but both return the same error. The other confusing thing is that this works on some servers but not on others without any obvious differences.

This feels like a permissions issue but I am at a loss as to what to try next.